# Update dynamic key in class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class, for example:

```
class Team {
  pointsFor: number;
  pointsAgainst: number;
  
  constructor(){
    this.pointsFor = 0;
    this.pointsAgainst = 0;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to make a method for this class where I can update the property by key for example:

```
updateStats = (bool: boolean, property: string, increment: number) =>{
  const key: keyof this = bool ? `${property}For` : `${property}Against`
  this[key] += increment
}
```

However I get an error that string is not assignable to keyof this, and if I force the type like

```
const key: keyof this = bool ? `${property}For` as keyof this : `${property}Against` as keyof this
```

then I get an error: "Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'this[keyof this]' and 'number'."

Is there a way to accomplish what I want here where I call `team.updateStats(true, 'points', 2)` and update `pointsFor`?

Comment: It's possible, but tricky. Are you sure you don't want a data model like `{ points: { for: number, against: number } }` instead? That would be _much_ simpler. And arguably better for lots of reasons.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `const key: string = ...`? `keyof this` seems like it wouldn't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend using string manipulation with TypeScript class properties the way you are trying to.

By using `keyof this`, you are essentially referring to all the keys of the class, like `pointsFor: number`, `pointsAgainst: number`, and `updateStats: Function`. As you can see, not all of them are numbers.

Another issue is that a `string` can be anything, so `updateStats(true, 'blah blah', 3)` could become valid if TypeScript didn't stop you.

It would be much better to constrain the specific properties you need to an object within the class with clearly defined properties.

For example:

```
class Team {
  teamProps: { [key: string]: { for: number, against: number }} = {
    points: { for: 0, against: 0 }
  }

  updateStats = (bool: boolean, property: keyof typeof this.teamProps, increment: number) =>{
    this.teamProps[property][bool ? 'for' : 'against'] += increment;
  }
}
```

You can access these properties with `<Team>.teamProps.points.for` instead of `<Team>.pointsFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do nearly everything with TypeScripts typesystem:

`TeamProp` takes a union of keys (`keyof this` in this case) and returns only strings, that match `${string}For` or `${string}Against`.

```
type TeamProp<K> = K extends `${infer P}For` ? P : K extends `${infer P}Against` ? P : never;

class Team {
    pointsFor: number;
    pointsAgainst: number;

    constructor() {
        this.pointsFor = 0;
        this.pointsAgainst = 0;
    }

    updateStats<P extends TeamProp<keyof this>>(bool: boolean, property: P, increment: number) {
        const key = bool ? `${property}For` : `${property}Against`
        this[key] += increment
    }
}

const t = new Team()

// Works
t.updateStats(true, 'points', 1);

// Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"points"'.
t.updateStats(true, 'foo', 1);
```